# Find the smallest divisor which brings a given Dividend below a given threshold

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given a pair of non-negative integers:

- $L\leq2^{256}-1$
- $H\leq2^{256}-1$

I'd like to find the smallest positive integer value of $z$ such that $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{z}\leq2^{256}-1$

---

If we use $z=H$, then we get $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{H}=2^{256}+\frac{L}{H}\geq2^{256}$

So we by the least need to use $z=H+1$

---

Recall that we are looking for the smallest value of $z$ such that $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{z}\leq2^{256}-1$

Or in other words, we are looking for the smallest value of $z$ such that $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{2^{256}-1}\leq z$

---

Let's split the problem into two cases:

- $H>2^{256}-1-L$
- $H\leq2^{256}-1-L$

---

**First Case:**

$H>2^{256}-1-L\implies$

$L>2^{256}-1-H\implies$

$\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{2^{256}-1}>\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+2^{256}-1-H}{2^{256}-1}=\frac{(2^{256}-1)\cdot(H+1)}{2^{256}-1}=H+1$

So the smallest positive integer value of $z$ that we can choose in this case is $z=H+2$

---

**Second Case:**

$H\leq2^{256}-1-L\implies$

$L\leq2^{256}-1-H\implies$

$\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{2^{256}-1}\leq\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+2^{256}-1-H}{2^{256}-1}=\frac{(2^{256}-1)\cdot(H+1)}{2^{256}-1}=H+1$

So the smallest positive integer value of $z$ that we can choose in this case is $z=H+1$

---

Does the reasoning above consist a valid proof?

I feel that in the first case, where I show $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{2^{256}-1}>H+1$

I still need to explain why $\frac{2^{256}\cdot H+L}{2^{256}-1}\leq H+2$

If this is indeed a flaw, then how can I resolve it?

Is there any other flaw that I'm possibly missing here?

---

Thank you very much!

Comment: What you have done is generally fine. On the main point where you correctly say your answer needs more explanation see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N=2^{256}-1$ to simplify the working.

Then you require
$$z\ge \frac{(N+1)H+L}{N}=H+\frac{H+L}{N}$$

There are therefore two cases.

If $N\ge H+L$ then $z=H+1$

If $H+L>N$ then $z=H+2$

NOTES

Because both $H$ and $L$ are at most $N$, the most that $H+L$ can be is $2N$.

A special case is $H=L=0$. In that case it would look like $z$ could be zero. However the original condition involved $z$ being a positive divisor and so $z=H+1$ works in this case also.

Comment: Shouldn't that be $z\geq\dots$?

Comment: For your second comment - we obviously cannot divide by zero.

Comment: What I meant to say is that in your top equation up there, $z$ should be "greater than or equal to", and not "less than or equal to".

Comment: Sorry. My mistake - a typo.

Comment: Also, regarding "can be $2N$, are you sure it's not "cannot be $2$ or higher"?

Comment: No. Each of $H$ and $L$ can be at most $N$.

Comment: Hence $\frac{H+L}{N}$ can be at most $2$.

Comment: Yes. That is correct.